# Ubuntu 20.04 - Can't increase partition size as my unallocated storage comes before my system partition

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, storage

**Goal**: Increase the partition size of my system (Ubuntu 20.04)

---

**I tried to**: Use Gparted (picture below)

---

**Problem**: My system partition comes after my unallocated storage.

---

A little over a year ago I gave my Ubuntu partition 30+ GB, I thought it was enough since I was just going to use it for programming and I would place most my files on another drive, well I was wrong...

So now that I want to increase the partition size just a bit more I'm not able to do so as my system is placed **after** my unallocated storage.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want to do or do I have to wipe my partition and start over?

[image]

Comment: Back up important data.  Will have to move both partitions to the left, the tiny one and p6. Then add space.  Has to to be done from live USB.  Probably have problems booting, but beyond my knowledge to fix without google.  A start over is the easiest, since no booting problems.

Comment: @crip659 That' sad, but I will do so. The tiny partition is the swap, once I wipe it along the P6, will those merge into my unallocated or do I have to do something? to have a single unallocated of 70+

Comment: Looked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) ? With a Live USB you can move partitions around - Backup before! - There are many similar questions in this forum

Comment: @kanehekili I see!!! working on the backup, tyvm :)